# JSON.NET Deserialization Property Name conversion to ExpandoObject with custom ContractResolver

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net, deserialization

I have this JSON:

```js
{"firstName": "John","lastName": "Doe"}
```

This JSON.NET Contract Resolver:

```cs
public class CustomContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver{      
  protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
  {
    return propertyName.Replace("_",""); 
  }
}
```

And I have this WebApi Controller method with uses an expando to a partial update of a db row using the provided fields:

```cs
public virtual int Post(int id, JObject content)
{
  var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(content.ToString(), new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver() });
  db.Update<Person>(id, obj)
}
```

I expect the deserialized expando to have properties `first_name` and `last_name` to match my model/db column names, but instead its properties still match the JSON. Deserializing directly to `Person` has `first_name` and `last_name` works, as L.B. helped me discover below, but my db layer wants an Expando for partial record updates, otherwise it'll blow away any properties of the `Person` that are not specified by the json and therefore `null` in the Model.

What can I do in the ContractResolver to convert the properties for an Expando?

Comment: Are you sure your DB layers expects exactly expando, maybe `IDictionary<string,object>`?

Comment: Yes, there is an explicit check for `t == typeof(ExpandoObject)` after which it dynamically builds the column list from the `Expando` cast as an `IDictionary<string,object>`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this ContractResolver while deserialization

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(
            json, 
            new JsonSerializerSettings { 
                    ContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver() 
            });
```

---

```
public class CustomContractResolver : Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        return propertyName.Replace("_",""); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I'm doing in the code in my question (except my resolver is camelCasing the property name), but the object's fields aren't getting changed.

Comment: @ThePants I tested it before posting and it works.  This is the Person class `public class Person
        {
            public string first_name { get; set; }
            public string last_name { get; set; }
        }` and this is the json `{"firstName": "John","lastName": "Doe"}`

Comment: @ThePants BTW: Note that I deserialize to `Person` class not `ExpandoObject`

Comment: Yeah, I had just noticed that and tried it out. It does indeed work when I deserialize to Person, but not to an Expando. Why doesn't it work for Expandos? My db layer wants an Expando do to partial record updates with.

Comment: Ok, so I think I see the source of the issue. The `ResolvePropertyName` method always works in the same direction from Model -> Json... which is why my original Resolver didn't work... which also explains why Expandos wouldn't work, because they don't have any PropertyNames to Resolve. I'm still at a loss as to how to write a ContractResolver that would actually work with them, though.

Comment: I've updated my question to fix the `ResolvePropertyName` function, and ask specifically about Expandos. Thanks for your help so far.